# How to restore visual studio nuget packages?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I cloned and loaded a visual studio project .net 4.8. I see all these references here

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried a package restore and I get

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
```

I tried uninstalling one of them and reinstalling the same version from nouget package manager, but that specific reference still has the error. I check the packages folder and all the packages are there. The .csproj file is pointing to them. So why is visual studio not correctly referencing them here?

I have .net 4/4.7/4.8 installed too.

Comment: You might try clearing the package cache and then restore again.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it, I just needed to install .net 4.8 SDK/targeting pack (developer pack).